# UISegment Control - Set selected according to day (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

Like the title says, I'm trying to set the selected segment control according to day. My segment control includes the days of the week and i also have a date and time label. The proper day has to be selected when the view is open

I know i have to do something with:

```
segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
```

I'm getting the date with:

```
showDate.text = "Date:  " + DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.medium, timeStyle: .none)
```

But I'm not sure how to set the selectedIndex to be dependent on date and show the appropriate day. I'm still new to swift and still learning, any help will be very much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: So your question is basically "how do I get the current day of the week as a number?", correct?

Comment: I managed to get that piece of code but i don't how how to set the current day when the view is loaded

Comment: Put the code in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Should i use an if statement or something? And the code i found is not working, how can i get the numbers of the days of the week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISegmentedControl` indexes start from 0. If you have all the days of the week in it its indexes start from 0 and end in 6.

You can get a day's index in weekdays using this

```
let day = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
```

this returns 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday... 7 for Saturday

So you can assign `selectedSegmentIndex` as follows

```
    if (2...6).contains(day) {
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = day-2
    } else {
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    }
```

Comment: My UISegmentControl is only Monday - Friday so i set it as: 
```segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = day-2```
But on Saturday is got back to Monday, Sunday nothing is selected and then it goes back to Monday. How can i fix the Saturday?

Comment: @Javy14 if the date is Mon - Friday select appropriate segment in segmented control. If date is sunday or saturday select nothing. Is this you want?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want

Comment: I think thats what i was looking for! I also have another question about displaying the next day Date when i tap the next day and previous date when i tap the previous day. Should i ask another question?

Comment: @Javy14 Yes. Ask a new question